# How do I change the home screen's Email icon to go to GMail instead of the default Email app on the Samsung Galaxy S?

Tags: att, samsung-galaxy-s, email, gmail, home-screen

On the bottom of the home screen there is an icon for EMail. I don't ever want to use the default Email app. I only use GMail and would rather use the Google GMail app. How do I change where the icon goes and how do I remove/disable the other app?

[image: att captivate home screen]

at&t Captivate (Galaxy S)

Android 2.1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

click "applications", click menu button, click "edit". You should now be able to drag the email icon away. Then just replace it with the gmail icon by dragging it to its place.

The other way is to configure the mail application to connect to gmail with imap or pop, but I wouldn't recommend it since gmail app is much better.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually after clicking the menu button I had to click View Type, then customizable grid. But otherwise those directions did it! Thanks!!!

Comment: @Adam: Ok. This seems to be different between AT&T Captivate and Samsung Galaxy S i9000 then. But nice that you got it working! :)

Comment: +1 Didn't know you could do that, thought the bottom row of icons were hard coded!

Comment: Worked exactly as you described with my captivate on Rogers. Just had you click-hold the icons before I could drag them.