# Set default mail application on Samsung Continuum?

Tags: email, samsung-continuum

I recently picked up the Samsung Continuum (love the phone!). The ticker is awesome except that it launches the default mail application when I click the mail icon. I don't mind the mail application but I much prefer the Gmail application.

I've noticed that it will launch whatever default application is set. The problem is I can't seem to change the default mail application. The Mail app is not listed in the Applications list, so I can't use it to "Clear Defaults". I've also tried the DefaultApp application and that doesn't list the application either.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this the same question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/31/how-do-i-change-the-home-screens-email-icon-to-go-to-gmail-instead-of-the-defaul

Comment: No. The Continuum has the special dedicated "Ticker" screen that gives you notifications. When you click the notification for new email it only ever launches the default email application. I'd like for it to launch the gmail application.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't allow you to clear defaults, you may be out of luck as that more than likely means Samsung hardcoded what is used to open the message.